# CSS: Unable to position elements correctly below a sticky navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a website with enough text, so that you are able to scroll (http://jsfiddle.net/o0emtyug/1/). On the right side I added some buttons for special functions on my website, which are positioned `fixed` and have a spacing using CSS `top:XXpx;`. Furthermore I placed the buttons within my menu bar div container `nav-primary`.

Using my JQuery script `sticky-nav.js` the menu bar is always visible on my page, even if I scroll down the page. So if I scroll down the page my menu bar stays on top of the page.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want my buttons to keep the same distance height from the menu bar all over the time. For this I will need to remove the CSS code `top:XXpx;`. If I do this, my buttons disappear. I tried changing `top` to `margin-top` but this did not solve my problem.

Anyone able to tell me what I need to do in order to arrange the buttons exactly  below the menu bar, with the same distant height when scrolling?

Comment: There is no javascript on your fiddle, or css

Comment: @DarrenSweeney that's whre SO comes in :p

Comment: I embedded the CSS and JS as a external resource (on the left side)

Comment: @JaromandaX My bad, writing it now...

Comment: @OtakuKyon It's not working and really, that's not the best use of jsfiddle - add e.g. jQuery sure, but not what you want someone to look at

Comment: Check your browser console ... none of the external resources load

Comment: This is due to the HTTPS encryption of jsfiddle. In the chrome url bar there is a shield on the right side you have to click, in order to allow standard http contents to load

Comment: that's a shame, i don't use google's peronal information gathering tools ... I mean, chrome

Comment: orignally linked fiddle works if you go to http://jsfiddle.net/j8tqjx73/8/ ... note http not https

Comment: I'm sorry, this was my fault.. I thought running the normal http stream will redirect me to the https version of this site..

Comment: (I can't see that "the menu bar is always visible on my page, even if I scroll".. I'm missing something?) OK just enabling jQuery on the Javascript panel!

Comment: Ok updated: http://jsfiddle.net/o0emtyug/1/

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what you changed (in case I have different issue?)

Comment: Yes, there's a little "JAVASCRIPT" button  on the middle of the screen, you click on it to enable Jquery and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a test button with Absolute positioning in the nav bar, so it doesen't seem to be in the container, but inherits its position:

```
#test {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

Here the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0emtyug/6/)

Remember that Absolute positioning is relative to the Body **or** the first container that have a specific `position`. In this case, `top:100px` is relative to `.nav-primary`, that has `position: relative`.

Comment: So in order to make this working with my colored circle buttons I will need to set them absolute?

Comment: I don't get it. For example: ´#ca-view´ was set by me to absolute and is relative to ´.nav-primary´ but it does not show up like your added button.

Comment: Be careful that the css you're including doesn't overwrite the rules in the fiddle. If possible add all the relevant Js and css in the fiddle (and remove from the external link) so we can modify it.

Comment: The problem of these buttons is that you're setting `position: fixed` to `#right-navigation li`. See line 800-820 of the css in [this **fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o0emtyug/8/).